# Como pasar mas de un parametro a un filtro personalizdo de Django, estando el filtro dentro de un tag for

Tags: python, django, filtro

Necesito hacer un filtro personalizado que se le aplique al iterable de un tag for, que reciba 3 argumentos:

1. El propio array iterable
2. El forloop.counter del for anterior a este
3. Una cadena

He probado estas dos variantes y me da error desde el mismo IDE:

> {% for item in array %}
>
> {% for value in array|get_key:forloop.counter+","+"tribunal" %}
>
> {{ value }}
>
> {% endfor %}
>
> ...

> {% for item in array %}
>
> {% for value in array|get_key:[forloop.counter,'tribunal'] %}
>
> {{ value }}
>
> {% endfor %}
> ...

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con: ***El forloop.counter del for anterior a este***? ¿Es un `for` anidado dentro de otro `for`? ¿Es un `for` que viene justo después de otro `for`? ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr? Saludos

Comment: Hola, como ve en el ejemplo que puse en la pregunta, tengo 2 for anidados, el counter es el del for de un nivel mas alto. Pero de igual manera, si supieras como hacer eso con cualquier otra variable, me serviría. Lo que intento hacer es pasar mas de un parametro a un filtro personalizado que hice, pero como se ve en el ejemplo es dentro de un tag for, por lo que tengo ciertas limitaciones.

Comment: Revisa la documentación, creo que `forloop.parentloop` te sirve para lo que buscas hacer, aunque ya te dieron un respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien indica [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), los filtros toman uno o dos argumentos. Por lo tanto, hay que tomar caminos alternos para conseguir esta funcionalidad. Entre las opciones a tomar, las tres más expeditas (en mi opinión) serían...

### Registrar una Simple Tag

Las [Simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) aceptan cualquier cantidad de argumentos. Puedes definir una, establecer sus parámetros, registrarla, y usarla en tus templates para conseguir lo que deseas:

**Template:**

```html
{% for item in array %}
    {% get_key array=array counter=forloop.counter string='tribunal' as key %}
    {% for value in key %}
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**filters.py**

```py
@register.simple_tag
def get_key(array, counter, string):
    # ... Haz acá lo que tengas que hacer, ya teniendo disponibles las tres variables...
    return iterable    # <-- se supone que esto debe ser un iterable que hayas definido
```

**No obstante**, como dices que tienes un filtro ya creado, quizás se te haga más fácil implementar una de las dos opciones siguientes.

### Encadenar filtros propios

Puedes crear dos filtros, uno que reciba dos argumentos y devuelva un tupla de ellos, y otro que reciba esa tupla y el tercer argumento.

**Template:**

```html
{% for item in array %}
    {% for value in array|pass_array_and_counter:forloop.counter|get_key:'tribunal' %}
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**filters.py**

```py
@register.filter
def pass_array_and_counter(array, counter):
    return array, counter

@register.filter
def get_key(array_and_counter, string):
    array, counter = array_and_counter
    # ... Haz acá lo que tengas que hacer, ya teniendo disponibles las tres variables...
    return iterable    # <-- se supone que esto debe ser un iterable que hayas definido
```

### Encadenar filtros builtins y usar la template tag `{% with %}`

Puedes apalancarte en la funcionalidad de los filtros `stringformat` (para convertir el contador a una string) y `add` (para concatenar las strings, junto con un delimitador), junto con la template tag `{% with %}` para crear un contexto que contemple una variable `data`, que contenga la información que necesitas.

Luego, puedes invocar la función `str.split(<delimitador-que-hayas-elegido>)` para obtener cada variable dentro de tu función.

**Template**

```html
{% for item in array %}
    {% with data=forloop.counter|stringformat:'s'|add:','|add:'tribunal' %}
        {% for value in array|get_key:data %}
            <p>{{ value }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

**filters.py**

```py
@register.filter
def get_key(array, data):
    counter, string = data.split(',')
    # ... Haz acá lo que tengas que hacer, ya teniendo disponibles las tres variables...
    return iterable    # <-- se supone que esto debe ser un iterable que hayas definido
```